# How to change ActiveX code to using in chrome plugin?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, activex, google-chrome-devtools, npapi, ppapi

I have a ActiveX code write by MFC ,it is c++ code to get client pc net interface information,and will exec some test like ping.
  Now,it should use in chrome plugin. How should i do? use npapi or ppapi ? can i use ActiveX c++ code?

Answer (score 3):

- PPAPI can't make arbitrary calls to native code, so it won't be useful for you.
- NPAPI would work, but since NPAPI is deprecated in Chrome and slated for removal, it would be a bad idea to port to NPAPI for Chrome at this point.
- No, you can't just use ActiveX in Chrome.

It's likely that Native Messaging in a Chrome extension is the best way to do what you are describing. There are a number of similar questions here already about getting OS information in Chrome that have more detailed answers.